# Approximate a continuous field with a field of class $C^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-fields

I was reading an application about the fundamental group of $\mathbb S^1$, such as the following

> Every continuous field of vectors tangent to $\mathbb S^2$ admits a singularity.

But it makes use of the fact that if $X:\mathbb S^2\to \mathbb R^3$ is a continuous vector field that has no singularities, then given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a field of class $C^1$ which is less than $\varepsilon$ away from $X$.

I would like to know why this is true, and if there is any bibliographical reference of where to find this that would be great.

Comment: Do you mean, there is a continuously differentiable field $Y$ with $\max\|X-Y\|<\epsilon$?

Comment: @FShrike Yes, that's just what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially because $S^2$ is a $C^1$ manifold, and as such admits a $C^1$ partition of unity. Indeed, if $F:S^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a continuous function, we can take an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $S^2$ such that on each element of the cover the value of $F$ does not vary too much, say on $U\in\mathcal{U}$ $F$ takes values that are within a $\delta$ of $F_U\in\mathbb{R}$. Then taking a $C^1$ partition of unity $\lambda_\bullet:\mathcal{U}\to C^1_{\text{loc}}(S^2;\mathbb{R}^2)$  subordinate to $\mathcal{U}$ we have that $\sum_{U\in\mathcal{U}} F_U\lambda_U$ is a $C^1$ function that is within an $\epsilon=\epsilon(\delta)$ of $F$.

Since $S^2$ is compact we may take $\mathcal{U}$ to get an explicit dependency of $\epsilon$ on $\delta$, but compactness is not necessary. Indeed we have the following more general density result:

**Theorem:** Let $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}\cup\{\infty\}$, $M$ be a $C^r$ manifold (of finite dimension($\dagger$), but not necessarily compact). Then $C^r(M;\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $C^0(M;\mathbb{R}^d)$, when the latter is endowed with strong topology.

Recall that strong ( = fine = Whitney) topology coincides with weak ( = compact-open = topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets) topology.

(See [Equivalence of Definitions of Hirsch and Wall of Strong $C^r$-topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4303460/169085) for the definition of strong topology and [Hirsch's Differential Topology vs Rudin Functional analysis definition of weak and strong topology.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3800868/169085) for the definition of weak topology.)

This is Theorem 2.2 in Hirsch's book *Differential Topology*, p.44; see there for details. One can e.g. also replace the target with an anonymous manifold, and replace $0$ with with a positive integer (in which case one would need convolutions).

($\dagger$) There is also an infinite dimensional version of this, assuming the manifold is separable and the local model is a Banach space with a certain "$C^r$ extension property" (a Banach space $B$ has the $C^r$ extension property if there is a $C^r$ function $\Phi:B\to \mathbb{R}$ (with finite $C^r$ norm) that vanishes outside the unit ball at $0$ and is $1$ on a smaller ball at $0$). For this see Ruelle's *Elements of Differentiable Dynamics and Bifurcation Theory*, p.144, which is a special case of a theorem from Bonic & Frampton's paper "Smooth Functions on Banach Manifolds".

Comment: +1. This is a much better answer than mine. I wrote mine making a few implicit assumptions I didn’t bother to check in detail, because I’ve never actually studied differential topology / geometry myself!